# How can I execute some part of code at time that I want?

Tags: ios, swift

I create `functionLibrary.swift` class to call some functions in some different ViewControllers. Problem is when I execute the app, the `println` function in the `ViewController.swift` works first in spite of it is after the some other lines that I called from `functionLibrary`.

Here is the logIn function from ViewController. (funcLib is a value that type of functionLibrary)

```
 @IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject) {

        var bodyData = ["op":"users","op2":"login","id":"","id2":"","id3":"","users_emailAddress":"asdasd@gmail.com","users_password":"asdasd"]

        var requestData = funcLib.JSONStringify(bodyData) // This turns the data to string
        var responseData = funcLib.HTTPPostRequest(requestData) // This is the http post request. Returns a bool and a Dictionary

        println(responseData)
```

Here is the output

```
(false, [:]) //responseData
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7aad7290> { URL: http://asdasd.asdasd.com/services/index.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 57;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sun, 26 Jul 2015 21:09:39 GMT";
    Server = asdasd;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.4.43";
} }// The println in HTTPPostRequest
{
    auth = *********;
    "user_id" = ***;
} // The println in HTTPPostRequest
```

The code is working fine. There are no runtime errors. But like I said println is executed first. How can I execute it after request and response Data get the data from funcLib functions?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey if you have solved then add the solution as answer and not as an EDIT to question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `funcLib.HTTPPostRequest` schedules an async closure and returns immediately, without waiting for the HTTP response. The async approach is fine, but of course you cannot expect to find in `responseData` any data returned from the HTTP server, and of course the println in `logIn` will be executed immediately, while the println of the HTTP response will happen later, when the actual response will be received by the closure.

Comment: thanks, i understand the problem. how can I solve it? is there sync closure or something?

Comment: Yes, there may be a sync equivalent. But in a UI application, async handling of server responses is almost always better.  Look for example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) for inspiration and examples.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem with using `dispach_async()` method.

Here is the new `HTTPPostRequest()` function:

```
func HTTPPostRequest(link:String, bodyData: AnyObject, completion:((data: NSData?) -> Void)) {


        println("HTTPPOST")

        if let requestURL = NSURL(string: link){

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = JSONStringify(bodyData)
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data, response, error) in
                completion(data: NSData(data: data))

                if let error = error {
                    println("error:\(error)")
                    return
                }

            }.resume()

       }

   }
```

And here is how to call the `HTTPPostRequest()`:

```
    @IBAction func logIn(sender: AnyObject) {

        var bodyData: AnyObject = ["op":"users","op2":"login","id":"","id2":"","id3":"","users_emailAddress":"asdasdasd","users_password":"asdasd"] as AnyObject

        let response: () = funcLib.HTTPPostRequest("http://asdasd.asdasdasd.com/services/index.php", bodyData: bodyData){data in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){


                if let data = data {
                    let responseData = NSData(data: data)
                    let responseDic = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data , options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary

                    println("\(responseDic)")

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```